# How to use fill when there are characters in csv with R

Tags: r, read.csv

For example I have the following table.csv:

```
    ,title1   ,title2
f1   ,2     ,5
f2   ,3     ,"8s"
f3   ,8     ,13
f4   ,"21,4"  ,"19,4"
f5   ,16     ,12
f6   ,12
```

And when do I use

```r
read.csv(file=file.choose(),header = T,sep = ",",quote = "\"",row.names=1,fill = TRUE,dec = ",")
#---> fill = T
```

Generate but fill = T no working

```r
      title1 title2
f1      13.0     10
f2      11.0     8s
f3      18.0     13
f4      21.4   19,4
f5      16.0     12
f6      12.0
```

Well my **problem is generated by 8s** that does not **allow filling with NA**. **Is there any solution to this?**

Comment: You may need to specify `na.strings = ""`

Comment: interesting,it works, show <NA>

Comment: You can check with `is.na(df1$title2)` it would be TRUE .  it is just the print method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the `na.strings`, it would read the blank as `NA`

```
read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep=",", quote = "\"", 
          row.names = 1, fill = TRUE, dec = ",", na.strings = "")
#      title1 title2
#f1       2.0      5
#f2       3.0     8s
#f3       8.0     13
#f4      21.4   19,4
#f5      16.0     12
#f6      12.0   <NA>
```

Comment: there is something that I have noticed, the comma has not changed by point

Comment: then I realized that it only makes the change if in the whole **column they are numeric type**

Comment: @royer yes, that is the case.  Here you have a delimiter `,` and `dec` as `,` which confuses